# changing models.integerfield() using ajax

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

it doesn't work even when i put a number for testing in front of device.degree in views.py.
its my input and submit button :

```
    <div class="col-log-7 px-5 pt-7">
      <p>Rooms tempreture:</p>
      <input type="number" placeholder="degree"> 
      <button type=submit text="submit degree" onclick=update_degree()>
    </div>
```

ajax :

```
      function update_degree() {

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xhttp.open("POST", "degree", true);
      xhttp.send();
    };
```

urls.py :

```
    path('degree',views.degree_views,name='degree'),
```

views.py :

```
@csrf_exempt
def degree_views(request):
    device = Device.objects.get(id=1)
    device.degree = 10
    device.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

can anyone tell me what should i do ?